# Automate a Vim script to write text to a file

Tags: vim

I am writing a script that runs on the command line and I want to be able to automatically append some static text to a file using Vim.

This is a simplified version of what I have:

```
insert_text() {
    vim -s ./text.txt new.txt;
}
```

Then it would run on the command line by typing insert_text. Inside text.txt I have tried things such as:

```
iSome Text:wq
```

This puts me in insert mode and writes the text but I don't know how to leave insert mode in this way. The :wq never works and is instead written to the new.txt.

Comment: If you just want a command, and the requirement is so simple as you describe, why you want to use vim to achieve it? a sed one-liner would be more straightforward.

Comment: Thanks, I don't know how to use sed but I wil look into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to append text to a file you don't need any special tools. For instance you can just use:

```
echo "Some text" >> myfile.txt
```

or if you have a large block of text

```
>>myfile.txt cat <<EOF
some
long
block of text
EOF
```

If you want it at the start of a file you can use a temporary file to do this. For instance:

```
echo "Some Text" | cat - myfile.txt > /tmp/file && mv /tmp/file myfile.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

This will append `someText` at the beginning of line 1:

```
vim -c "1 s/^/someText" -c "wq" test.txt
```

When you run a command from the terminal and you want Vim to exit after that, instead of `:wq` do `+wq`. For example:

```
vim +'SomeCommand' +qa
```

Comment: Thanks Rafael, I haven't tried this yet but I will.